Feynman diagrams for $W$-pair and photon product after electron-positron annihilation
Someone know how to draw Feynman diagrams for $W$-pair and photon product after electron-positron annihilation?

It could be $e^-e^+ \rightarrow ZZ \xrightarrow{p^-p^+} W^-W^+$ in the vicinity of a proton antiproton pair.

What's with the photon? Do you mean $e^+e^-\rightarrow W^+W^-\gamma$? Without the gamma, it might be a t-channel neutrino, at tree-level.

@JEB Yeas, i mean  $e^{+} + e^{−} \to W^{+} + W^{−} + \gamma $

So that is $t$-channel scattering via neutrino exchange (b) or $s$-channel annihilation with a photon of $Z$ (a), which also shows what appears to be a non-standard model $V^0$.
The addition of a photon in the final state falls under radiative corrections and came come off any charged line in the initial, final, or generally the intermediate state.
Radiative corrections are generally a hassle in analyzing data. Here they are "internal", and add coherently.
External radiative corrections are bremsstrahlung events in the experimental apparatus either before (in fixed-target) or after the scattering event. They are incoherent.

